# How to Set up Zend Framework 2 On Server

Tags: linux, apache, zend-framework, server

I am trying to deploy a Zend Framework 2 Application.  I want to set the DocumentRoot to the public folder (inside zend).  It does not currently seem to be working.

Using a Centos 6 Os

The path looks correct and I have restarted the server (its a vps).

I think I'm updating hte right file because if the path is incorrect I get a server error.  Currently it is taking me to the public_html folder and I have to navigate to the public.

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: What is the path to the file you're changing, and can you edit your question to include its contents?

Comment: Tim, I ended up following the instructions here and it worked.  http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/file-management/changing-the-document-root-with-root-access

Comment: Should the whole project sit in the public_html folder or do I just want the public folder in there and the rest in the home directory?  I appreciate the help.  Thank you.

Comment: If you have control of the virtual host, you don't want to use the public_html folder at all - you upload your project and modify the DOCUMENT_ROOT of the vhost to point at your project's public folder instead of public_html.

Comment: Got it,  So I put it in the home directory and point the host to look in the public folder.  Thanks for the help Tim I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the steps on the link below and was able to point the server to the correct point.  Following Tims suggestion I am in the process of moving everything out of the public html directory and pointing the server to home/public/index.php.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/file-management/changing-the-document-root-with-root-access